# How to create raster attribute table to a raster data using gdal python?

Tags: raster, gdal, attribute-table, colortable, land-classification

I classified a remote sensing data and saved it as a raster using Gdal python. I want to create a raster attribute table for this classified result.. my classified raster has five classes with 1,2,3,4,5 representing classes A,B,C,D,E respectively... Is it possible to assign color to each class.. since it is a single band raster image..

Comment: Do you want a Raster Attribute Table, or do you just need a Color Table?  They are separate in gdal.